# Where do I find the ROS Community?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

After a few days checking this site (answers.ros.org) frequently, I've realized that only a few people come here to answer questions and give answers.

In fact, there are questions (including very interesting ones) without any answer too. And most of them, only have 1/2 answers.

It's quite surprising since it seems like many contributors (see the different repositories) are helping in the development of this awesome project.

I'd want to ask you if there is any other place where I can find more activity about ROS. It seems like the community here is not so active :( (maybe because of Summer?)

Thanks for your answers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38807/where-do-i-find-the-ros-community?/) by [1morelearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/2840/1morelearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2012-07-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PerkinsJames](https://answers.ros.org/users/2621/perkinsjames/) on 2012-07-15**:
To what other communities are you comparing the ROS community to?  While i find that ROS does have a smaller community than, say, the linux kernel, the community here is actually quite strong compared to similar robot frameworks or transport frameworks in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is the ros-users mailing list where you can hear community announcements and other more general discussion:

https://code.ros.org/mailman/listinfo/ros-users

However, questions should be asked right here on answers.ros.org.

---

Originally posted by [Benjamin Johnston](https://answers.ros.org/users/1983/benjamin-johnston/) with karma: 50 on 2012-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that you'll find that there is a lot of activity on the ros-users mailing list in regards to general ROS discussion, as Benjamin Johnston mentions in his answer.

In addition to that, there are many groups formed around various elements of the ROS project, such as device drivers, motion planning, infrastructure, etc.  I think that the best way to get involved with these is to start with the ROS special interest groups (http://ros.org/wiki/groovy/Planning/)  These groups are currently planning the direction of the ROS platform in the future, and many have their own mailing lists or communication mechanisms.  In the past, there have been meetings via IRC, e-mail, Google Hangout, and at ROSCon 2012.

Additionally, you can participate in API reviews, such as the [unique_identifier](http://ros.org/wiki/unique_identifier/Reviews/2012-07-06_API_Review?highlight=%28StackReviewCategory%29) review that just concluded.

As for answers.ros, it's just a matter of questions coming in faster than people can answer them.  I try to answer a few questions a day (and I know a few people try to do the same), but the volume of questions is overwhelming (often duplicates or poorly formed questions).  The best way to fix this is to have people adhere the support guidelines better, and try not to ask so many duplicate questions.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-07-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8